# Shooting 5D Mark II w/ tethered storage but standard capture

Tags: camera

I know that it is possible to shoot tethered with tools like [gphoto2](http://gphoto.org/doc/remote/). What I am wondering is if it is possible to shoot from the camera as usual and simply use the tether for storage? I am aware of options like the eye-fi cards but I prefer the tethered option. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the [DarkTable](http://www.darktable.org/) with Nikon D7000. I have tried only basic functions such as adjusting shutter speed. I was not able to adjust white balance by K-scale, only by the built-in presets (incandescent, etc). My camera had to be available BEFORE DT was launched. Otherwise it works fine. DT is basically a raw editor with "darkroom" editor mode, so new shots can be immediately processed.

[Entangle](http://entangle-photo.org) specialized specifically on tethering  also looks promising, although I have not tried it yet.